# How to sum columns fron 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sum

I have a tables like this

```
select * from t1;

   ID        SAL
----- ----------
    1        100
    2        200
    3        300

select * from t2;

    ID        SAL
------ ----------
     1        100
     2        200
     3        300
     4        100

select * from t3;

    ID        SAL
------ ----------
     1        100
     2        200
     3        300
     4        100
```

But the output should be like this:

```
id         sal
-------------------
1          300
2          600
3          900
4          200
```

Comment: Hint: UNION ALL

Comment: @arun \kumar please check the answer hope it helps your need

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL` with `GROUP`:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(SAL) FROM
(
    SELECT ID, SAL FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, SAL FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, SAL FROM t3
) AS T
GROUP BY ID
```